# Defining different fonts (color) per file in org-agenda

Tags: org-mode

My org-agenda view is made out of 5-6 files. Can one define a different face (mainly color) per file?

Comment: What portion of the entry do you want to color differently?  The file name should already be shown by default as part of the `org-agenda-prefix-format`.

Comment: yes the name of the file is there but all files have the same color. i would love to define a different color per filenname entry

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand lisp, but the following worked for me.  It does not change the color of the complete entries, but it changes the color in which the file name (or rather: category name) preceding each entry is displayed.

1. Add a category name to each of your agenda files, e.g.
   `#+CATEGORY: Home`
   in one file and
   `#+CATEGORY: Work`
   in another.  It's conceivable that this step is completey unnecessary and that you can continue using file names.
2. Add the following to your `.emacs` file:

   ```
   (add-hook 'org-finalize-agenda-hook
     (lambda ()
       (save-excursion
         (color-org-header "Home:" "azure" "black")
         (color-org-header "Work:" "RosyBrown1" "red"))))

   (defun color-org-header (tag backcolor forecolor)
     ""
     (interactive)
     (goto-char (point-min))
     (while (re-search-forward tag nil t)
       (add-text-properties (match-beginning 0) (+ (match-beginning 0) 10)
                        `(face (:background, backcolor, :foreground, forecolor)))))
   ```
3. Customize the lines of the form
       `(color-org-header "Home:" "azure" "black")`
   to your liking.  [Here's a list of predefined colors.](http://raebear.net/comp/emacscolors.html)

Comment: Just tried the solution and found out that in Emacs 26.1 the hook's name is `org-agenda-finalize-hook`.